# unpad NSData from decrypt on ios

Tags: ios, nsdata

i decrypt a string with IOS but the HEX output is a bit loger than the real string
it's have some more 00 at the end of string that generate a problem when i use the NSData.

is possible remove that 00 generated?

after i saw the hex my data tryed to remove manualy them, and it's seem work with

```
[dirtyData setLength:[dirtyData length] - 3]
```

but idk how count programmatically how many 00 there are ad the end

i belive i need somethink like that php function but compatible with NSData hex

```
function unpad($text){
       $pad = ord($text{strlen($text)-1});
       if ($pad > strlen($text)) return false;
       if (strspn($text, chr($pad), strlen($text) - $pad) != $pad) return false;

       return substr($text, 0, -1 * $pad);
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you stored somewhere the length of the unpadded data (in your example 3) then you can use:

```
NSUInteger unpaddedLen = [dirtyData length] - 3;
NSRange unpaddedRange = NSMakeRange(0, unpaddedLen);
NSData* unpaddedData = [dirtyData subdataWithRange:unpaddedRange];
```

Note: `NSData` is unmutable, that's why your setLength did not work. The other way is to use `NSMutableData`:

```
NSMutableData* dirtyData;
// fill dirtyData as just it would be NSData
[dirtyData setLength:[dirtyData length] - 3]; // will now work
```

Comment: could be i've explained bad, but my problem is get in some way the length of the unpadded data
 dirtyData is altray a NSMutableData
i wrote that `[dirtyData setLength:[dirtyData length] - X];` just for test i need get the X

Comment: Sorry it's obscure to me what your problem is. You don't know how many 00 characters are added at the end of the data?

Comment: yes it that my prolem che count `[dirtyData setLength:[dirtyData length] - X]`

Comment: I don't know which cryptographic algorithm do you use and whether it provides you the length of the original data. If not, you will have to store it yourself in the plain data _before_ the encryption let's say as the first several bytes, and then extract it after decryption.